# How to debug TTYs being blank / agetty?

Tags: 16.04, text-mode

Sometimes all text-mode terminals on my machine become blank (just a cursor in the top left corner, like on tty8+ by default) after a while and I can't reproduce it reliably.
What logs can I check or how should I filter `journalctl` to see everything related to TTYs?
I tried to use `strace` on `agetty` processes and they don't do anything at all.

The login prompt is there but it's not shown. I can login and execute commands, but the screen stays blank (or with messages left from boot). `agetty --reload` changes nothing.

Kernel 4.4.0-22.40
Intel graphics on i3-3110M 8086:0166
xserver-xorg-video-intel 2.99.917+git20160325-1ubuntu1

Comment: You can read all information from *another* terminal process using the `stty` command. Enter `stty -F [tty device]` to manipulate the specified tty device. See `man stty` and [this excellent page](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) for more. Does this answer your question?

Comment: I tried changing some options, making them identical to the set on a machine with working tty but nothing changed, it's still blank and does not show login prompt. From `journalctl` I've figured that the login prompt is there, and I can login and execute commands, but the screen stays blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on Arch some time ago. The problem was the 4.4 kernel. After upgrading to >=4.5 the problem was gone.